# What programming languages will be supported by EOS?

Tags: dapp

I understand that EOS supports C++ at launch and can support any language that compiles into WebAssembly (WASM)

Here is a [list of languages](https://github.com/appcypher/awesome-wasm-langs/blob/master/README.md) that compile to or are compatible with WebAssembly.

I am wondering when it will be possible to create dApps using Javascript or if it is currently possible to create dApps in any other language.

Comment: There is also `eosjs` for interacting with the blockchain via Javascript: https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs

Comment: Microsoft has added the WASM toolkit, allowing smart contracts to be written in C, C++, Rust and others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a new active project trying to adapt the EOSIO API to TypeScript using AssemblyScript called [eos-typescript](https://github.com/eos-typescript/eos-assemblyscript-api).
They have a [telegram group](https://t.me/joinchat/GrBgI1IsE32yqThRJbwD7g).

I think TS is easier to mantain and read and will definitely reduce the barrier of entry and attract more dapp developers.
Compilation from TypeScript to webassembly is very efficient and plenty performant for complex smart contracts.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you look into [NectarJS](https://github.com/NectarJS/nectarjs), it allows you to compile JS into many different native scripts, including WASM.

While I've not used it myself, it appears to be as simple as `nectar --target wasm file.js`

Answer (score 5):

It should be possible now! All that a person would have to do is create a wrapper around the C/C++ API created by EOSIO.  Once that wrapper is created, the code would then be compiled to *wasm* and uploaded to the blockchain as normal.

Answer (score 4):

You can do TypeScript also, here's an example https://steemit.com/eosio/@eosargentina/developing-typescript-javascript-on-eos

Answer (score 3):

You'll be able to create contracts with all sorts of languages, perhaps even Siri could make you one.

However, this is found on the [EOS Wiki](https://github.com/eosio/eos/wiki/Smart-Contract#introduction-to-eos-smart-contracts)

> "Other toolchains in development by 3rd parties include: Rust, Python, and Solidity. While these other languages might appear simpler, their performance will likely impact the scale of application you can build. We expect that C++ will be the best language for developing high-performance and secure smart contracts, and plan to use C++ for the foreseeable future."

I believe Dan Larimer himself wrote that section according to a reply of his on Telegram